# Translation of a video URL

Tags: 8

I have a content type Book with a field called demo that references to a media (remote video - we must provide a youtube URL).
As a first step I create a new node in french and I put a youtube URL ex: [www.youtube.com/abc](http://www.youtube.com/abc) and I save. then I add a new translation to english and I put another youtube URL for this demo field ex: [www.youtube.com/zyx](http://www.youtube.com/zyx). Now when I go back to the firstly created node in french, I see that the video that is displayed is the one whose URL is /zyx instead of /abc ! Any idea why?
PS: the field is listed as translatable here :
/fr/admin/config/regional/content-language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You translated the wrong part. Your node has a reference field to a media. This field must not be translatable, it will always reference the same media ID.

Instead enable translation for the media entity, and the remote video source URL field.

Translate the media. Translate the node (e.g. title, but not the media reference). Done.

At the end you have got one node with two translations, one video media with one ID and two translations. Both node translations point to the same the media ID, and Drupal will automatically pick the correct translation for the video.

Comment: Thank You so much ! and if there is no translation, so for example if for  a certain node i want the video /abc to appear for all languages , then I don't add any translation to the media  and by default for all languages the video abc will apear correct ?

Comment: Yes, untranslated references will fallack to the original language.

Comment: Thank You sooo much !